# HP Z440 regedit does not have msahci but I changed bios to AHCI

Tags: bios, windows-registry, nvme, ahci

I don't know if this is much ado about nothing but I went into bios and changed IDE to AHCI rebooted downloaded the AHCI controller drivers and my registry does not show msahci. Can i manually add that to registry or do nothing? Windows 10 Pro boots normal. There are no problems. The reason why I ask is that I plan to get a Z turbo pcie to m2 adapter so my boot drive will be the new nvme ssd and another forum said I have to be AHCI to do that. Thanks

Comment: Is there a storahci key instead? It seems to have been renamed. But not sure whether it is needed if you did already switch to AHCI in BIOS and Windows boots fine. AFAIK switching this register entry was required before switching it on BIOS.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just checked and there is a storahci key. Seeing as everything runs normal I'll just leave it be for now. If I have problems making my new nvme ssd the boot drive at least that will give me a starting point to research. Thanks again.